# why def __str__(self): return self.title is not changing the object's title in the database?

Tags: python, database, django-models

I created a database by django but when changing the object name using

```
  def __str__(self):
     return self.title
```

does not change. Here's the code:

```
def __str__(self):
     return self.title


class Class(models.Model):

     Status = (
               ('doing', 'doing'),
               ('done', 'completed')
     )

     title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
     description = models.TextField()
     done = models.CharField(
             max_length=6,
             choices=Status


created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Comment: The `__str__` method goes into the class and you are missing a `)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your model should be:

```
class Class(models.Model):

     Status = (
               ('doing', 'doing'),
               ('done', 'completed')
     )

     title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
     description = models.TextField()
     done = models.CharField(
             max_length=6,
             choices=Status


created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True) 

def __str__(self):
     return self.title
```

Comment: I changed the order but still haven't changed the title.

Comment: class Aula(models.Model):

    Status = (
              ('doing', 'Fazendo'),
              ('done', 'Completo')
    )

    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    done = models.CharField(
            max_length=6,
            choices=Status
    )
# proximos são campos de boa pratica para verificar quando novo dado entrou
# no sistema


created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


def __str__(self):
    return self.title